# Filling in textbox on IE with excel macro, multiple name elements

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am try to enter a value from my excelsheet into a textbox in IE. Until now I am successful in opening the correct website.

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.navigate "http://test.com" 'dummysite
IE.Visible = True

IE.document.GetElementsByName("value") = "value from sheet"
```

To fill something in the textbox the element named "value" needs to be given a desired input. The problem is the this element name "value" occurs multiple times in the code of the website. I have tried something like (since it is the 7th element named value),

```
IE.document.GetElementsByName("value")(7) = "value from sheet"
```

but that does not work either. This is a part of the site source. I am trying to fill in the value element on the second row.

```
<td>
    <input name="@_20_0_T" type="hidden" value="T_AN">
    <input name="_20_0_T" type="text" size="40" value="">
</td>
```